# LARAVEL - Base table or view not found: 1146 Table doesn't exist (SQL: select * from )

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model

I have a Mysql database `minho.win` and a table called `utilizadores`.

I created a model class `php artisan make:model Utilizador`

When I do `php artisan tinker` and then do `App\Utilizador::all()` I get this error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'minho.win.utilizadors' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `utilizadors`)'

Why is it looking for a table named `utilizadors`? How can I make it look for the right table - `utilizadores`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify the table in your model:

```
class Utilizador extends Model {
    protected $table = 'utilizadores';
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Answer (score 0):

so you have to protect your table in you Model
something like that:in Your Model

```
protected $table = "utilizadores";
```

put your field's name in this array, it will seem like that:

```
protected $filliable  = [
"id", 
""
];
```

Answer (score -1):

in migrations check whether the table name is spelt correctly I had this problem where there was an _ before the table name

```
public function up()
{id();
    Schema::create('_employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->
```

remove the _ and fresh migrate